# converting string into char

Tags: c++

I know I can do this by `str.c_str()`,
but I do not want a character constant. I want a char so that I can make some modifications.

```
char* removeDup(char *s)
{


        int len = strlen(s);
        int p,q, idx = -1;
    for(p = 0; p< len; p++)
   {
    char temp = s[p];
    bool flag = true;
    for(q=0;q<p;q++)
    {
        if(s[q] == temp)
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == true)
    {
        s[++idx] = temp;
    }
}
    s[++idx] = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

if I call this function as below, I get errors;

```
string s = "abcde";
removeDuplicate(s.c_str());
```

I need to convert this `s` into `char` and not `const char`.

Comment: My suggestion would be to pass in a `string` instead and skip `char*` completely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the underlying data from a `std::string` You can use:

**[string::data()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/)** or **[string::c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)**, both return a `const char *`.

In either case the returned data is `const char *` because the memory for it is allocated in some read only implementation defined region which an user program is not allowed to modify. Any attempt to modify the returned `const char *` would result in **Undefined Behavior**.

So you cannot and should not(through `const_cast`) modify the returned character string.

The only correct way to achieve this by creating a new `char*`, allocate it, and copy in the contents from the `const char*`:

```
std::string myString = "blabla";
char* myPtr = new char[myString.size() + 1];
myString.copy(myPtr, myString.size());
myPtr[myString.size()] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to use any extra buffer

Comment: @Roger then use a `const_cast<char*>` but it's a bad idea. Proper solution is to copy the data as @Luchian Grigore suggests.

Comment: @Roger well, that's impossible. A C-style cast to `char*` will break the program, as it will result in undefined behavior. Why not use std:string's functions to achieve what you want?

Comment: @Roger You need to use an extra buffer - the one returned by `c_str` is owned by the original string - so you can't modify it.

Comment: @Cicada: casting away the constness would be an UB.

Comment: @Als precisely why I added `but it's a bad idea`.

Comment: This isn't immediately relevant - but if you're using c_str() ever you'll probably need to allocate a new buffer.  For example, if you return the c_str() result and your original std::string goes out of scope, your c_str() result becomes invalid.

Comment: I modified your answer to accommodate all the facts.I will delete my answer.Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I'd suggest `std::vector<char>` rather than a raw dynamic array. Memory leaks are no fun to track down.

Comment: @Mike Seymour you can also use `std::unique_ptr<char>` if you want to keep the pointer semantics.

Comment: @WTP: Indeed, but it needs be `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, so that the array is correctly deleted.

Comment: @Dennis: you can't use `auto_ptr` since that deletes with plain `delete`, not array `delete[]`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Correct you are. I have never used it for arrays myself so I didn't realise there was a caveat there. Boost::scoped_array would be a better choice (as it would work!).
 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm

Comment: @Dennis `std::vector<char>` would be an even better choice, since it takes care of both the allocation and the deallocation.  (Really, the only valid choice is to rewrite the function to use iterators---and to hopefully make it readable at the same time.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making a copy of the buffer, calling your function, and then setting the original string to the new char buffer.  Something like:

```
std::string str("some string");
char tmp[str.length() + 1];
memset(tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));
copy(str.begin(), str.end(), tmp);
str = removeDup(tmp);
```

Using the const buffer returned by c_str() directly and modifying it is asking for trouble.  The buffer is owned by the string object and you should think of modifying that as breaking encapsulation and at minimum implementation dependent.

Comment: More than breaking the encapsulation(which probably one could get away with) casting away the const is a guaranteed Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Note that variable-length arrays are a non-standard extension to C++. If you want portability, use `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy it.

```
string str = "Hello";
char * cStr = new char[str.size()];
memcpy(cStr, str.c_str(), str.size());
```

Comment: And don't forget to delete the dynamic array when you're finished (or better yet use `std::vector<char>`). Also, it looks like the evil function in the question requires a zero-terminated string, so use `str.size()+1` to include the terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to legally make modifications to a `std::string` is through
it's member functions (including the access paths they indirectly 
provide).  Thus, you should rewrite your `removeDup` to take
`std::string::iterator` as arguments, something like:

```
std::string
removeDup( std::string& original )
{
    std::string::iterator current = original.begin();
    std::string::iterator end = original.end();
    while ( current != end ) {
        end = std::remove( current + 1, end, *current );
        ++ current;
    }
    original.erase( end, original.end() );
    return original;
}
```

(I think this does what your original code does.  I can't be sure,
because I couldn't really figure out your original code.)

From a design point of view, this is ugly; you should probably pass a
`std::string const&`, and return a new `std::string`:

```
std::string
removeDup( std::string const& original )
{
    std::string results;
    std::bitset<UCHAR_MAX + 1> alreadySeen;
    for ( std::string::const_iterator current = original.begin();
            current != original.end();
            ++ current ) {
        if (! alreadySeen.test( static_cast<unsigned char>( *current ) ) ) {
            results += *current;
            alreadySeen.set( static_cast<unsigned char>( *current ));
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

The only time you want to get a `char*` from a `std::string` is to pass
it to legacy code (or C).  In such cases, `std::string::c_str()` is the
approved method; if the function you are calling requires a `char*`,
then:

- if the function doesn't actually modify the string (it's not const
  correct, but this is the case for many C functions), then use
  `const_cast` on the return value of `std::string::c_str()`, otherwise
- you must allocate a local buffer, and pass it:

  std::vector localBuffer( s.begin(), s.end() );
  localBuffer.push_back( '\0' );
  legacyFunction( &localBuffer[0], localBuffer.size() );

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this method from string:

**Copy sequence of characters from string:**
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/

eg. If you had a string 'str', you could do this:

```
char buf[str.len()+1]
str.copy(buf, str.len())

//terminate with newline
buf[str.len() = '\n']
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the realm of 'possible' as opposed to 'sensible' you could do:

```
std::string str("foo");
str = removeDup( std::auto_ptr<char>(strdup(str.c_str()).get() );
```

But rewriting in terms of std::string would be better.

Comment: Although this does assume that malloc and new are synonymous for chars.